# Overriding a virtual function with a covariant return type in a template derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, types

I would like to override a virtual function in a template-derived class. However, I would like to use the derived class as return type. Here is the corresponding code:

```
class Abstract {
  public:
    virtual Abstract* allocate() const = 0;
};
template <typename Derived>
class Base : public Abstract {
  public:
    Derived* allocate() const override {
      return new Derived;
    }
};
class Concrete : public Base<Concrete> {
  public:
};
int main() {
  Concrete c;
  delete c.allocate();
}
```

Unfortunately, my compiler does not recognize that `Derived` is actually derived from `Abstract` and fails with the following error message.

```
mwe.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class Base<Concrete>’:
mwe.cpp:12:25:   required from here
mwe.cpp:8:14: error: invalid covariant return type for ‘Derived* Base<Derived>::allocate() const [with Derived = Concrete]’
     Derived* allocate() const override {
              ^~~~~~~~
mwe.cpp:3:23: note: overridden function is ‘virtual Abstract* Abstract::allocate() const’
 virtual Abstract* allocate() const = 0;
                       ^~~~~~~~
```

Moving the `allocate` function into the `Concrete` class would solve the issue, but leads to code duplication, when creating multiple concrete classes. Is there a way to make the compiler aware that `Derived` is actually derived from `Abstract`?

Answer (score 2):

Modifying [Bernds idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62919503/#62920210) of introducing a type tag to distinguish the different `allocate` functions, we can create a simpler solution. The trick is, that we introduce the type tag in the `Abstract` class and that we override the `allocate` method without providing a default parameter (to avoid ambiguity). The drawback of the following solution is that we need to be able to change the signature of the `allocate` method in the `Abstract` class, which might not always be possible.

```
class BaseTag {};
class Abstract {
  public:
    virtual Abstract* allocate(BaseTag = {}) const = 0;
};

template <typename Derived>
class Base : public Abstract {
  public:
    Abstract* allocate(BaseTag) const override { return allocate(); }
    Derived* allocate() const {
      return new Derived;
    }
};

class Concrete : public Base<Concrete> {
  public:
};

int main() {
  Concrete c;
  delete c.allocate();

  Abstract* a = &c;
  delete a->allocate();
}
```

Comment: That is a nice idea, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate a covariant return type:

The point here is the class `Reintroduce`. Without it `allocate` would override the virtual function. With it, it hides the inherited function.

```
#include <iostream>

class Abstract {
  public:
    virtual Abstract* allocate() const = 0;
};

namespace details{
    class Reintroduce {};

    template <typename Derived>
    class AllocImpl : public Abstract
    {
    public:
        Abstract* allocate() const override {
            return new Derived;
        }
    };
}


template <typename Derived>
class Base : public details::AllocImpl<Derived> 
{
  public:
    Derived* allocate(details::Reintroduce = {}) const 
    {
      return static_cast<Derived*>(details::AllocImpl<Derived>::allocate());
    }
};

class Concrete : public Base<Concrete> {
  public:
};


int main() {
  Concrete c;
  delete c.allocate();
}
```

It would be great if we could implement it without `AllocImpl` but that would make the call ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that `Concrete` is not complete in `Base<T>` (neither `Base<T>`) (as for any CRTP).

So compiler don't know that `Concrete` inherits from `Abstract` yet.

Possible solution is to not use CRTP but regular inheritance:

```
template <typename Base>
class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    Derived* allocate() const override {
      return new Derived;
    }
};
class ConcreteImpl : public Abstract {
  public:
};

using Concrete = Derived<ConcreteImpl>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b10ee8da1159f3f6)

Comment: It's nice because that way you don't need a cast. But what if you want to return your covariant return type pointer wrapped in a "smart pointer"

Comment: Smart pointer are unfortunately not covariant :-/ you might still have both methods: the covariant one which returns the pointer, a not-virtual one which call the virtual one to wrap the result in the smart pointer.

Comment: In your sample you do just the opposite of "CRTP", by using a "mediator" class. Nice idea.