# Reusable member function in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, type-traits

I'm using this member function to get pointer to object:

```
    virtual Object* Create()
    {
        return new Object();
    }
```

It's virtual so I can get pointer to derived objects, now I'm doing it like this:

```
    virtual Object* Create()
    {
        return new Foo();
    }
```

It is working correctly, but I'd like to do something like this to prevent any mistakes and also to make it easier so I don't have to rewrite that function every time I make new class:

```
    virtual Object* Create()
    {
        return new this();
    }
```

I was trying to find how to do this but couldn't find anything useful, maybe it's not possible. I'm using MSVC compiler with C++17

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to retrieve the actual (dynamic) type of the object within the definition of `Create` inside the base class. Without the need of overriding `Create`. Am I right? If so, I don't understand why you accepted an answer that actually requires overriding.

Comment: Anyway, you are basically trying to solve the same problem as emerge in _clone pattern_ without _clone_ function overriding. This can be achieved with the help of CRTP; see, e.g., [this article](https://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/c-polymorphic-cloning-and-the-crtp-curiously-recurring-template-pattern/).

Comment: FYI: [SO: How to implement ICloneable without inviting future object-slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57405375/7478597) (about a somehow similar issue).

Comment: @DanielLangr mainly I needed to know how to do `new this()`, overriding isn't much problem for me, I just needed to prevent mistakes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get the type from `this` pointer as

```
virtual Object* Create() override
{
    return new std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rYeSQbbHHDcycWJo)

PS: Note that you still need to override the member function in every derived class. Depending on your demand, with [CRTP](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp) you can just implement `Create` in the base class. E.g.

```
template <typename Derived>
struct Object {
    Object* Create()
    {
        return new Derived;
    }
    virtual ~Object() {}
};
```

then

```
struct Foo : Object<Foo> {};
struct Bar : Object<Bar> {};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jG8rrKLrOnGCWFMX)

Comment: This would not work, because decltype(this) returns not the derived type. It returns only the declared type of this, which is type class where you defined this method.

Comment: @BerndBaumanns Sorry I didn't get what you mean, so in derived class it will refer to the derived class, isn't it? [LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yCx4G7LsZRiIHWW8)

Comment: You could do it like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62919503/overriding-a-virtual-function-with-a-covariant-return-type-in-a-template-derived/62920210#62920210

Comment: No, there is just a single implementation. I think he want's to generate an implementation for every derived class - this is possible via CRTP Pattern

Comment: @BerndBaumanns I got what you meant. Added to the answer.

Comment: unluckily `Object` can't  be `template` so the first solution is much better for me

Comment: If `Object` is a template, then `Foo` and `Bar` does not have the same base class. Typically, you have a single (non-template) base, and then some templated middle-class derived from it implementing CRTP, such as described [here](https://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/c-polymorphic-cloning-and-the-crtp-curiously-recurring-template-pattern/).

Comment: How can the method return Object* if you use the std::remove_pointer_t trait?

Comment: @Chris `decltype(this)` yields type `Object*`, `std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(this)>` yields type `Object`, then the `return` statement is same as `return new Ojbect;`, i.e. returns `Object*`.